# What is the state after a Thread crashed?

Tags: java, multithreading, crash, runnable

I am holding a list of Threads, each associated with a Runnable. After running them for a while, some of them changed into the state TERMINATED, though they shouldn't because of while(true) implemented in run(). So I guess those are crashed, am I right?

edit: each thread is independent from the others.

Comment: Each thread is on its own. May be those threads are done with processing and eligible for GC?

Answer (score 1):

They may have thrown an exception themselves, or been [interrupted by another thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html). I assume that there's no flow control you've implemented to jump out of the while loop (via an exception) and then cleanly complete processing.

Comment: my console was flooded with datas, if there was an exception i couldnt have notice it, i guess. but is it true that the thread state is going to TERMINATE? I am asking because i have no idea how to crash a thread  by myself.

Comment: @YannickWald Possibly because you can't "crash" a thread. All you can do is thow an Error or Exception which has not been caught. This leaves the thread in the same state as if it has exited normally.

Comment: @YannickWald The first thing to do is to get your console under control. Either filter to reduce the volume, or map it to a file you can search. Other programmers can tell you that an Error or Exception would cause a thread to go to TERMINATED despite a while(true) loop. Only your program can tell you about the specific Error or Exception, and you need that information to decide what to do next.